# How to add files using JSZip from remote URL in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, jszip

I'm using the map function to loop files inside a folder of my zip files but the folder is always empty. The fetching of the main file is working though.

Here is my code:

```
getZip = async () => {
  const zip = new JSZip();

  const url = await svc.getMainFileURL();  // will return a downloadable url from s3
  let response = await fetch(mcsURL);      // will fetch the data from s3 blob
  let data = await response.blob();        // and convert it into blob

  zip.file(`MainFile.xlsx`, data);         // add into the zip file

  const otherFiles = zip.folder("files");  // create another folder inside the zip file

  // Loop files from source data then insert it in the folder
  const list = sourceData.map(async (item,index) => {
    const fileUrl = await svc.getOtherFileUrl();

    const response = await fetch(fileUrl);
    const data = await response.blob();
    console.log(data);
    otherFiles.file(`${index}.xlsx`, data);
  })

  zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
  .then(function(content) {
      FileSaver.saveAs(content, `Zip File Name`);
  });
}
```

The logging of data returns fine but when I download the zip file it has only the data of the main file with folder files. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

There may be a problem with me using async/await but I can't figure it out. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I already solved it using `Promise.all()`. The `zip.generateAsync` function returns the zip file even if the promises from the map function are not resolved. That's why the folder is always empty. Here is my altered code:

```
getZip = async () => {
  const zip = new JSZip();

  const url = await svc.getMainFileURL();  // will return a downloadable url from s3
  let response = await fetch(mcsURL);      // will fetch the data from s3 blob
  let data = await response.blob();        // and convert it into blob

  zip.file(`MainFile.xlsx`, data);         // add into the zip file

  const otherFiles = zip.folder("files");  // create another folder inside the zip file

  // Loop files from source data then insert it in the folder
  const list = sourceData.map(async (item,index) => {
    const fileUrl = await svc.getOtherFileUrl();

    const response = await fetch(fileUrl);
    const data = await response.blob();
    console.log(data);
    otherFiles.file(`${index}.xlsx`, data);
    return data;
  })

  // If all prmises are fullfilled it will call the zip 
  // function and download it using the FileSaver library
  Promise.all(list).then(function() {
    zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
    .then(function(content) {
      FileSaver.saveAs(content, `Zip File Name`);
    });
  }); 
}
```